# Apache POI: Writing into excel with Java: opening Workbook, java.io.IOException: Cannot write data, document seems to have been closed already

Tags: java, excel

I have a class that stores Excel workbooks:

```
private Map<String, Workbook> workbooks = new HashMap();

public Workbook createWorkbook(String name)  {
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    workbooks.put(name, workbook);
    return workbook;
}
```

and a method that writes into a workbook with a specified name:

```
public void write(List<ExcelData> data, String workbookName) {
   Workbook workbook = workbooks.get(workbookName);
   CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

   ... write stuff

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(workbookName + ".xlsx");
   workbook.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();

   workbook.close();
}
```

However when I try to call method `write` two times for the same workbook:

```
testExcel.write(data, "Default");
testExcel.write(data1, "Default");
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot write data, document seems to have been closed already
```

error. I know I can open existing Excel workbook like this:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
```

But I was wondering if there's a way to bypass it by storing a `Workbook` variable. What are the inner mechanics at play? Is the variable becomes invalid after `workbook.write()` is called?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but within your method `write` you explicitely close the workbook.

Comment: @RobertKock, would it be a matter of removing/commenting the close line? I though I code call `workbook.open()` as easily as I can `workbook.close()`, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I see from javadocs (https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/) that after XSSFWorkbook.close() "no further operations, updates or reads should be performed on the document". It seems to call OPCPackage.close(), which "Close the open, writable package and save its content". However, I don't understand what they mean by "save its content". If I write workbook into a FileOutputStream, close file, then edit the workbook some more and then close it, those extra edits wouldn't influence the file, would they? So where does it save those edits?

Comment: Also, what is a better/more memory-efficient approach - to never call workbook.close() and to always get it from the Map and then push to FileOutputStream or close the workbook variable after every edit and later load it from FileInputStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the workbook itself you can store the name of work book in list

```
private List<String> workbooks = new ArrayList();
```

Rewrite the createWorkbook to store only the name of the excel sheet
Rewrite the write method so it creates a new workbook as follows

```
public void write(List<ExcelData> data, String workbookName) {

Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
```

... write stuff

```
 FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(workbookName + ".xlsx");
 workbook.write(fileOut);
 fileOut.close();

 workbook.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error mainly occurs when we try to write the contents of ***already closed*** workbook.

```
public void writeToExcel(File file) throws IOException {
    LOGGER.debug("Writing chunks data to excel {}", file);
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception raised while writing chunks of items {}", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        // This line will take of closing XSSFWorkbook along with SXSSFWorkbook
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

This code is the one is throwing the following exception

```
Exception thrown is:
Exception raised while writing chunks of items 
"Cannot write data, document seems to have been closed already"
```

Why we were getting this exception?
Have a look at this code

```
 private void instructionSheet(Resource resource) {
    try {
        InputStream in = resource.getInputStream();
        // This is try-with-resources block which is closing the XSSFWorkbook
        try (XSSFWorkbook xssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(in))) {
            workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(xssfwb);
        }
    } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException e) {
        LOGGER.error("The instruction sheet failed to create {}", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

You can notice that the ***second try block*** is try-with-resources block and is ***closing*** the workbook, Hence we were getting the exception.

We ***resolved*** it just by ***removing*** the second try block i.e

```
private void instructionSheet(Resource resource) {
    try {
        workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(resource.getInputStream())));
    } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException e) {
        LOGGER.error("The instruction sheet failed to create {}", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

You can notice in the first code block of this answer that we are closing the work book after writing the content to the file.

The ***close*** method called at finally block will take care of closing ***XSSFWorkbook*** instance along with ***SXSSFWorkbook***.